# Find the upper and lower sum of an integral with a floor

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm having some trouble and looking for some help with a problem i'm trying to solve. Without the floor function it would be easy but the floor has made it a bit trickier:

Find the upper and lower sum: 
$$
\int_1^2 \lfloor x+1 \rfloor dx
$$

As a start i can say $$\Delta x=1/n$$  and $$x_i=1+i/n$$

$$\\$$ $$\\$$ 
**EDIT:** Thanks for the comments, although I think I might have explained it poorly! I am trying to find the upper and lower bound equation, over a regular partition of the intervals: $$U_N\quad and\quad L_N$$

So for example the upper bound equation for: $$\int_1^2 f(x) \quad where \ f(x)=x$$ $$\Delta x =(b-a)/n=1/n \quad and \quad x_i=1+i/n$$ $$Hence \quad U_L =\Delta x \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)$$ $$=1/n[\sum_{i=1}^n 1 + i/n]=\frac1n[n+\frac1n(\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2})]$$ $$=\frac1n[n+\frac{n}{2}+\frac12]=\frac32+\frac{1}{2n}$$ 
$$Thus:\quad U_L= \frac32+\frac{1}{2n}$$

And that would be the upper limit, the lower is just when X_i = 1+(i-1)/n.
My trouble is doing all this for a floor function.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Within most of the intervals $[x_{i-1},x_i]$, the function just equals 2.  Within the final interval, the function gets as high as 3.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, I'm afraid i left a bit out of the question so I've edited the qn to make it clearer. Cheers!

Comment: All of the $m_i$ are $2$, as are most of the $M_i$.  Only $M_n=3$.  So $U_n=\Delta x(2+2+...+2+3)$ and $L_n=\Delta x(2+2+...+2+2)$

Comment: Are you trying to find the definite integral? That is actually pretty easy if you understand jump discontinuous functions and their properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We consider the function 
>   \begin{align*}
> &f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\
> &f(x)=\lfloor x+1\rfloor
> \end{align*}
>   and the definite integral
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_1^2 f(x) dx=\int_1^2 \lfloor x+1\rfloor    dx
> \end{align*}

---

> To calculate lower and upper sums we take  a *partition*  $\mathcal{P}=\{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ of the interval $[1,2]$ with 
>   $$1=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_{n-1}<x_n=2$$
>   The lower sum $L(\mathcal{P})$ and upper sum $U(\mathcal{P})$   of $f$ with respect to the partition $\mathcal{P}$ are  given as
>   \begin{align*}
> L(\mathcal{P})&=\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_{k-1})(x_k-x_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor x_{k-1}+1\rfloor(x_k-x_{k-1})\\
> U(\mathcal{P})&=\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor x_k+1\rfloor(x_k-x_{k-1})\\
> \end{align*}

We know the *[floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)*  $\lfloor x\rfloor$ fulfills
$$\lfloor x\rfloor \leq x < \lfloor x\rfloor+1$$
with points of discontinuity at the integers. Therefore

\begin{align*}
f(x)=\lfloor x+1\rfloor=
\begin{cases}
2&\qquad 1\leq x <2\\
3&\qquad x=2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

It's often convenient to represent the *floor function* by **[Iverson brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)**
\begin{align*}
\lfloor x\rfloor=\sum_{j\geq 0}[1\leq j \leq x]
\end{align*}
This way we get rid of the floor symbols $\lfloor$ and $\rfloor$ and can manipulate sums instead.

> Let's calculate the *lower sum* $L(\mathcal{P})$:
>   \begin{align*}
> L(\mathcal{P})&=\sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor x_{k-1}+1\rfloor(x_k-x_{k-1})\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j\geq 0}[1 \leq j \leq x_{k-1}+1](x_k-x_{k-1})\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^n2(x_k-x_{k-1})\tag{2}\\
> &=2x_n-2x_0\tag{3}\\
> &=2
> \end{align*}

**Comment:**

- In (1) we observe, that $j$ takes always the values $1$ and $2$, since $1\leq x_{k-1}<2$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ and so the inner sum is $2$.
- In (2) we do a little telescoping, leaving only elements $x_0$ and $x_n$.
- In (3) we only have to cope with the endpoints of the interval $[1,2]$.

> And now the *upper sum* $U(\mathcal{P})$:
>   \begin{align*}
> U(\mathcal{P})&=\sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor x_{k}+1\rfloor(x_k-x_{k-1})\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j\geq 0}[1 \leq j \leq x_{k}+1](x_k-x_{k-1})\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j\geq 0}[1 \leq j \leq x_{k}+1](x_k-x_{k-1})\\
> &\qquad+\sum_{j\geq 0}[1 \leq j \leq x_{n}+1](x_n-x_{n-1})\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2(x_k-x_{k-1})+3(x_n-x_{n-1})\\
> &=2x_{n-1}-2x_0+3x_n-3x_{n-1}\\
> &=3x_n-x_{n-1}-2x_0\\
> &=4-x_{n-1}
> \end{align*}

**Comment:**

- In (4) we split the last summand with $k=n$, since the inner sum consists of three summands in that case.

---

*Note:* Since the *mesh* of the partition $\displaystyle{\max_{1\leq k \leq n}}|x_{k}-x_{k-1}|$ tends to zero with growing $n$, we see that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_{n-1}=x_n=2$$
and therefore the upper sums tend to
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(4-x_{n-1})=2$$
the same value as the lower sums.

*Note:* Since the value of an integral don't change, when we change the function value of $f$ at *finite many points*, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\int_1^2 f(x) dx=\int_1^2 \lfloor x+1\rfloor    dx=2\int_1^2 dx=\left. 2x \right|_1^2=2
\end{align*}

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Not quite clear what you address! Some more hints?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Now I see. Thanks!

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Interesting! The Iverson brackets are especially useful in connection with sums. This is shown e.g in *[this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140225/sum-of-lfloor-k1-3-rfloor/1274784#1274784)*.