# Find closed formula for series

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

I don't know how to approach this.

Here's what I've done so far.

$ x$ | 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

$ y = \lfloor \sqrt x \rfloor$| 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3

$ z = x^2 $| 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100

$\frac{dz}{dx} = 2n+1$| 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19

This is part of my first university maths-module course work.

Comment: See the lengthy explanation here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669460/find-a-formula-for-sum-limits-k-1n-lfloor-sqrtk-rfloor

Comment: Which is a duplicate question.