# Find the greatest n for which the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor$ is a prime number.

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I've come across the sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor$$
According to [Find a formula for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669460/find-a-formula-for-sum-limits-k-1n-lfloor-sqrtk-rfloor)
I approached the formula:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor = n\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor-\frac{1}{3}\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^3-\frac{1}{2}\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^2+\frac{5}{6}\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$$
Now, programmaticaly I attempted this formula for first $100$ terms. The biggest possible $n$ for which this sum was a prime number should be $47$. Now, is there a precise mathematical approach to this? I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Why do you think that there should be "a greatest $n$" with this property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for $n\geq 1$, the sum $S_n$ is a positive integer which can be written as
$$S_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n \lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor =\frac{1}{6}\cdot\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor\cdot\left(6n-(2\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^2+3\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor-5)\right).$$
where $f_1:=\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ and $f_2:=\left(6n-(2\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^2+3\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor-5)\right)$ are positive integers.

Therefore if $f_1:=\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor>6$ (i.e. $n\geq 49$) and 
$$f_2=\left(6n-(2\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^2+3\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor-5)\right)\geq \left(6n-(2n+3n-5)\right)=n+5>6$$ 
(i.e. $n\geq 2$) then $S_n=\frac{f_1\cdot f_2}{6}$ is not a prime (because $S_n$ is the product of two integer factors both greater than $1$).

Hence the largest $n$ such that $S_n$ is a prime, exists, it is less than  $49$ and, according to your computations, we may conclude that it is equal to $47$ with $S_{47}=197$.

Comment: Let me get the understanding of this. So if floor(sqrt(n)) is greater than six, that means i am able to factor something out of the bracket and that means it cannot be ever a prime. What i don't get is the line of the inequality: (6n-(2floor(sqrt(n))^+3floor(sqrt(n))-5))>= (6n-(2n+3n-5)) = n+5>6

Comment: Because $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^2$ and $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ are less or equal to $n$.

Comment: Wait, I am still confused, would you please reveal it for me in more detail?

Comment: $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^2\leq n$, $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor\leq n$ imply $(2\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^2+3\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor-5)\leq (2n+3n-5)=5n-5$.

Comment: Ah, I missed that  $-$ sign there. Now it's clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69344/discussion-between-michal-dvorak-and-robert-z).