# How to calculate a special sum?

Tags: summation

Thank you for giving me an idea to try to find a way to calculate this sum: 
$$S= \sum_{i=0}^n \lfloor\sqrt{i} \rfloor$$

Comment: This is the page for [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: In addition, this is a duplicate of [Find a formula for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669460/find-a-formula-for-sum-limits-k-1n-lfloor-sqrtk-rfloor). If you have any further questions, please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and ask a new question including what you don't understand.